# mysqli in PDO constructor

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Hy everyone, i'm looking to a code wrote from another student, and he used the PDO abstract lever for the connection to the database.

Now i've problem with mysql function, for example with fetch_assoc (i think why it is implemented only in mysqli).
There's a way to connect with PDO and mysqli both?
something like:

```
new PDO("mysqli:host=$this->hostname;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
```

adding the "i" in mysql:host

Or there's something similar at mysqli::fetch_assoc() in mysql functions?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand why it says `mysql` there, it doesn't have much to do with the old mysql/mysqli php thingies. It's the database you're connecting PDO with. Read the PDO manual for how to use PDO

Comment: `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: This is all mixed up. Please post a little more code.  The `new PDO()` constructor should have a DSN string beginning with `mysql:host=...`

Comment: MySQLi and PDO are *APIs* to connect to a MySQL database.  They *cannot* work together.

Comment: And beyond that, PDO and MySQLi are two entirely different APIs, not compatible with one another.

Comment: Both mysqli and PDO are drivers for mysql servers. You should not mix them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to use PDO and MySQLi together, but there is an option to choose fetch style in PDO. You can see those styles in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

So, lets get to the example:

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // $sth = your statement
foreach($result as $row) {
   echo $row['name'];
}
```

Now the `$result` contains query results as associative array.

The answer was more simpler than you thought, wasn't it?

Comment: $sth is?! statement or something else?

Comment: It work!! THX all, i think it's time to read PDO documentation, but i've not much time...and implements and re-write 3rd part code is not so simple

Comment: Yea, to use PDO efficently, you should read the docs. Yu can't know the good features unless you read them. Happy Coding :)